# VBA iterate through list of names / Addresses to create the same invoice automatically

Tags: vba, automation, invoice

I want to make 97 invoices that are for the same thing and for the same amount, but with different names, addresses and invoice numbers within excel.

i.e. only cells that change are the invoice number (+1 of the previous one), the names (going down the column of a worksheet) and the addresses (also just down the list).

I figured out how to the advancement of the invoice number with this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Range("C4").Value = Range("C4").Value + 1

End Sub
```

But how do I cycle through the names and addresses?

Is there also a way to do this automatically as well as save the file names as a concatenation of the last + first names + another string?

I am more familiar with python and so VBA is totally new to me and sorry if this questions isn't well phrased / very noobish.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the names/addresses in a list format, just iterate through all the values in that list replacing the name, etc.

To automatically save/export the files, perhaps something like this:

```
Dim nWb As Workbook
Dim MyPath As String, MyFileName As String
Dim FirstName As String, LastName As String

FirstName = .Cells(x,y) -- cell with first name value
LastName = .Cells(z,y) -- cell with last name value

MyFileName = LastName & FirstName & "INPUT-WTV-VALUE"

If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".xlsx" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".xlsx"

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Where do you want to save this file?"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = ""
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    
MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

End With

NextCode:

With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End With
```

This will basically generate the pop-up window you usually see when saving a file.